# HttpWebRequest with client certificate fails

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am using Visual Studio Mac (latest version) and need to fetch data from an IIs server (vaersion 10) with a GET request and by passing a client certificate.

Unfortunately the IIs answers with an RST packet and shows the error:

```
The I/O operation has been aborted becourse of either a thread exit or an application request.
```

I know apple uses ATS (I am using iOS 10.3.3).

I guess this has something to do with the client certificate and IIS not accepting it.

Can someone point me to a differnt mono api where I can append the client cert to a GET request?

My code so far is as follows (with `request.GetResponse()` waiting until timeout...):

```
X509Certificate2Collection certificates = new X509Certificate2Collection (certificate);

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(this.uriString);
request.ClientCertificates = certificates;

request.Method = "GET";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Accept = "application/json";
request.UserAgent = UserAgentString;
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse ())
{
  this.webResponse = response;
  stream = response.GetResponseStream ();
}
```

Comment: can that be a TLS 1.2 problem? IIs 10 not accepting cert with TLS 1.2 ?

Comment: 1. Have you config `ATS` in your iOS app? Here is document [ats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/ats) 2. Is your `IIS` support `Https`? 3. Can you add more `error messages` and in which `line` did you get the error message?

Comment: IIs (Version 10 on on Windows 2016) is configured for https (TLS 1.2). ATS is disabled as far as possible:

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT

IIs (Version 10 on on Windows 2016) is configured for https (TLS 1.2). ATS is disabled as far as possible: 

  <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
  <dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>

We found out that our GET request is only passed through to our binaries (our .dll) when in IIS Manager the SSL Settings for client certificate is set to "Ignore". Obviously the client certificate our binaries need internally is swallowed by IIs then.

When setting "client certificate" to "Accept" the GET request is not passed through and does not reach our binaries.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT

I now have set up nginx on the Windows server to accept the ssl request from our iPad and to proxy the settings through to IIs. Proxying in general does work but I have not found a way yet to proxy pass the client certificate through to IIs. Any hints on that?

kind regards,

Robert

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT

Here you see, its always "internal server error" :(
<failedRequest url="https://staubzeh.geh.ins.local:443/XXX/v1/List"
siteId="1"
  appPoolId="ThinPrint Mobile Print"
  processId="5048"
  verb="GET"
  authenticationType="NOT_AVAILABLE"               activityId="{800000C6-0000-F700-B63F-84710C7967BB}"
               failureReason="STATUS_CODE"
               statusCode="500"
               triggerStatusCode="500"
               timeTaken="124328"
               xmlns:freb="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2006/06/iis/freb"
               >

Comment: Through the error message, I think it's not the problem with the client certificate. Seems your `IIS` hasn't been configured well. You missed the `authenticationType`. Set the authenticationType and then you can test the sever through the website. Once the website is success to connect the sever, move on your step to  apps.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Are you talking about setting "authentication type" header in the HTTP request or are you talking about a config option for "authentication type" in IIs? If the latter, where do I find this configuration option?

kind regards,

Robert

Comment: The latter one.

Comment: I had a talk to our windows staff (I am the iOS developer) and he said: We are not authenticating to an IIs account - instead we use a client certificate per user but we pass that cert through IIs to our dlls, which do the authentication.

Besides, everything used to work until I updated iOS from iOS 7 to iOS 10 :(